# byte addressing and cache

Tags: memory

http://6004.mit.edu/currentsemester/tutprobs/caches_answers.html

Given DM: a direct-mapped cache.

S2: a 2-way set-associative cache with a least-recently-used replacement policy.

FA: a fully-associative cache with a least-recently-used replacement policy.

The questions below present a sequence of addresses for memory reads. You should assume the sequences repeat from the start whenever you see "...". Keep in mind that byte addressing is used; addresses of consecutive words in memory differ by 4. Each question asks which cache(s) give the best hit rate for the sequence. Answer by considering the steady-state hit rate, i.e., the percentage of memory references that hit in the cache after the sequence has been repeated many times.

Which cache(s) have the best hit rate for the sequence 0, 16, 4, 36, ...?

The answer says for DM, location 4 and 36 collide. Why? Something to do with the byte addressing, I suppose. Could someone explain, please?

Comment: First of all you should write all necessary Information here (and not only link it). This is for example the Cache size. Also: the linked Problem 4A says that 4 and 36 collide, you write that 0 and 36 collide and that you don't understand that.

Comment: Sorry Werner Henze I mistyped. I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

In Problem 4A the cache is 8 words long with one word (4 bytes) in each cache line. Direct-mapped cache means that the complete cache is always backing a continuous block of memory, here it is 32 bytes, so you get cache Content 0..31 or 32..63 or 64..95 or ...

When accessing the first 0 the cache is empty, you get a miss and 0..31 isloaded into the cache.
When accessing 16 and 4 you get a cache hit.
When accessing 36 you get a miss and 32..63 is loaded into the cache.
When the loop starts again you get a miss and again 0..31 is loaded into the cache.